# How to disable Tomcat from handling /WEB-INF requests

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

I have a web application deployed on Tomcat. At the moment every request at `{myApp}/WEB-INF` is handled by Tomcat (by showing 404 at the moment). I would like all paths to be handled by my application.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You just define a servlet that handles the requests and add a mapping ... in the same you would handle any other URL.   The reason that you are getting 404 is that no servlet has been mapped for that URL.

Comment: I tried to find a solution for this online. Nothing relevant to this. Also I checked Tomcat documentation and could not find something.

Comment: no this is different. In my Spring application, every request must be authenticated. Any request to any path, my app responds with 401, except for this path. This is happening due to a local folder named WEB-INF in the deployed application directory. I would like Tomcat to not check for local files in the deployed application.